# How to access sharepoint 2013 site owners with Rest API?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, rest

I have recently started sharepoint. I don't have more exprience. My question is simple. I would like to get information about site owners with rest api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SP.Site object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246828(v=office.15).aspx) exposes [SP.Site.owner property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246231(v=office.15).aspx) to get or set the owner of the site collection.

REST endpoint:

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/site/owner
```